# add another attribute to Magento products

Tags: magento

I have developed a magento extesnions that allow customers to upload their products to my stores and my problem now is :
How to configure Magento to  add attributes to  products (i want to add another attributes like price ,sku ,...etc ) ?
For example color , phone number , e-mail so that my customers can add their own data , and o can manage it through my admin interface .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you'd have to create new **Attributes Sets** for your customers/uploaders to work with.

A good thing in general is to use different attributes sets depending on the type of products you're dealing with; but in your case you could as well store and display customer data (in that case the uploader of the product?) in **attributes**, attached to a new **Attribute Set** that gathers everything you need.

You can basically customize the whole backend for products via Attributes Sets. You'll find them in the Catalog > Attributes menu. Should be the easiest way to go. Then you can match your extension to work with those.